# jsPDF not working .html function with Angular 12 in Google Chrome

Tags: angular, jspdf

The jsPDF (version 2.5.0) .html() function just loading and can't download the given HTML table in Angular 12 with Google Chrome - but in Edge works.

Here is the Ang 12 sample [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yfvdbk)

I found a working version in Angular 10 with jsPDF 2.1.0 version, but I could not figure out what is the problem.

Here is the working Ang 10 sample [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vtuj3b?file=package.json)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me both links are working in Chrome (Version 97.0.4692.71) and Edge. Please check your console for errors, or clear your cache. You can have errors also because of Chrome extensions, you can prevent it in Incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! In Incognito mode I had to enable 3rd party cookies for stackblitz otherwise I got an error. In Incognito it works and I figured out that in Google Chrome the Grammarly for Chrome blocked this jsPDF .html feature, but just in Angular 12, 13!

Comment: @ArnoldVakaria did you find any solution?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar as I wrote above in my case in Google Chrome  the Grammarly extension app for Chrome blocked this jsPDF.html feature, but just in Angular 12, 13

Comment: Gotcha, it's now universal issue and listed as bug in issues list at https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3370